# Why i'm getting just text instead of HTML using JQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a H1 tag & i want to get `HTML()` of this element on button click but right now getting just text instead of HTML. How can i get proper HTML?

My Code:-

```js
$(function(){
  $('button').click(function(){
    alert($('h1').html());
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<h1 style="color:indianRed">Heading 1</h1>

<button>Click</button>
```

Comment: The `h1` does not contain any HTML markup, just a text node, what were you expecting?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should use [`outerHTML`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/outerHTML):

> The [`outerHTML`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/outerHTML) attribute of the Element DOM interface gets the serialized HTML fragment describing the element including its descendants. It can also be set to replace the element with nodes parsed from the given string.

```js
$(function(){
  $('button').click(function(){
    alert($('h1').get(0).outerHTML);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<h1 style="color:indianRed">Heading 1</h1>

<button>Click</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

`outerHTML` in javascript

```js
$(function(){
$('button').click(function(){
  alert(document.querySelector("h1").outerHTML);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<h1 style="color:indianRed">Heading 1</h1>

<button>Click</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

The `.html()` function return the inner html of an element, to get the `outerHTML` of any given element, try to wrap it inside a container then get his html using `.html()`.

```
$(function(){
  $('button').click(function(){
        var elHTML = $('<div></div>').append($('h1'));
       alert(elHTML.html());
   });
 });
```